# Murder -Death -Kill the [Civilisation] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[civilisation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilisation) does not have any description or guidance on its use, its used on only 6 questions all of which explicitly they are asking about civilization world building and the tag is created using the UK version of the word where SE has US english as the standard for tags. 
[What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Answer (score 21):

All six questions look like they should have [world-building](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building) instead. That makes [civilisation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilisation) a good candidate for destruction via synonyming.

Comment: I'm in favor of this, but if so should we not edit the name to be US-english to keep the SE standards?

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith Probably not necessary. The point of synonyms being to redirect to the correct tag (including canonical spellings), it serves the purpose fine as is.

Comment: I created that tag a little while ago to gather together some things that seemed like they needed *something.* I picked "these questions are all about big sprawling societies." World building might do just fine. :)

Comment: @doppelgreener Would you mind putting together a short answer to that effect? I don't see this answer taking off like a rocket, so maybe there's an unmet need for a voting alternative. :)

Comment: It's possible the voting is hesitant pending the other meta about when to do this stuff getting settled, at a guess.

Comment: It seems this synonymization/merge never ended up happening at the time. I recently came across this and completed the merge (adding both [civilisation] and [civilization] as synonyms of [world-building]).

Comment: @V2Blast thanks! I also just tried to upvote this question before I realized I asked it myself years ago.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith: Haha, I've definitely come across some old posts that I didn't realize were mine when browsing meta :)